# Powershell - Determine Sunset and Add Time

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script that determines my local sunrise and sunset.  However, my end goal is to run a function at 45 minutes past sunset.  I know I can't use AddMinutes(45) as that only works with Get-Date.  I tried to format the output of the value returned for "sunset", but even formatted to match Get-Date, it still doesn't work.  Is there some other method I could use?

```
$Daylight = (Invoke-RestMethod "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=35.608081&lng=-78.647666&formatted=0").results
$Sunrise  = ($Daylight.Sunrise | Get-Date -Format "HH:mm")
$Sunset   = ($Daylight.Sunset | Get-Date -Format "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using PowerShell Core, the properties `Sunrise` and `Sunset` from the object returned by your API query should already be of the type [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-6.0#methods), however in Windows PowerShell, you would need to cast `[datetime]` to them to convert them from *string*. Then `.AddMinutes` method would work without issues, if you're looking to run a function **45 minutes** past Sunset you can try the following assuming this could be a scheduled task:

```
$Daylight = (Invoke-RestMethod "urlhere").results
$sunset = [datetime] $Daylight.sunset # => [datetime] only needed in Windows PowerShell
if([datetime]::Now -ge $sunset.AddMinutes(45)) {
    # run function here
}
```

Or if you want your script to execute and wait until the right time, you can use a loop:

```
do {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
} until([datetime]::Now -ge $sunset.AddMinutes(45))

# run function here
```

Comment: All good Santiago.  Working well now.  Thank you!